# How do I layout tables?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website and I'm trying to create a.. well I don't know what it is called exactly but it basically includes a list, a button, an image, a title and some text.

All elements are in seperate tables.

What I'd like to do is get the title to be top with the image underneath that, the list to the **RIGHT** of both the image and the title, the text undereneath the list and the button to be at the center berlow everything.

```
<table border="1" width="350px" height="50px" class="title_table">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <multiline>Basic plan set-up</multiline>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table border="1" width="350px" height="125px" class="image_table">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <img editable="true" mc:edit="feature-img1" style="display: block;" width="102" height="100" src="http://promailthemes.com/campaigner/layout2/white/blue/img/feature-img1.png" alt="feature image1" class="feature-img" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="list_table">
    <table border="1" width="350px" height="300px">
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <p>What's included:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<table border="1" width="350px" height="125px" class="button_table">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="submit" value="To checkout!" class="submit">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you maybe post a quick sketch / mockup?

Comment: It makes no sense at all to have those elements in separate tables.

Comment: @SW4 I just tried but because of regulations I can't (need 'x' amount or rep!)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/H4cm3/6/ 
Just have look at this.. i just modified ur html and let me no if it is correct

Comment: @Quentin the reason I'm doing it in seperate tables, is because I'm going to put them on one table so I can orientate it landscape and do a border radius

Comment: It still makes no sense to have them in tables at all. Tables describe a relationship where everything in a row has something in common and everything in a column has something in common. If there is only one cell in the table, there is nothing for the data in it to relate to. This the table makes no sense.

Comment: @user3218194 close! but I need the what's included above the list but otherwise moreorless perfect!

Comment: @Quentin it's not meant to make sense! Tables (in HTML) structure out a webpage like using <div> and <section> except for smaller things, like how they do navigation bars are in tables, it's just for structure purposes not data relation or data representation

Comment: @user3906099 That was true, but not with the current standards in webdesign. Tables are a very outdated way of structuring a webpage, and using `div`'s and CSS is strongly recommended nowadays.

Comment: @user3906099 — It's how people did navigation bars in 1996 before CSS was well supported. This century we have actual layout tools and don't need to use hacks.

Comment: @Quentin I am using CSS, to design the tables and everything like that, it's just a lot easier to do it in tables for a website that isn't (and doesn't for that matter) need fancy web development, it may help enhance and practise my skills but it doesn't need it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

**DEMO: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25LAL/)**

**Code:**

```
<table border="1" width="350px" height="50px" class="title_table">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <p>Basic plan set-up</p>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <p>What's included:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>item</li>
                <li>item</li>
                <li>item</li>
                <li>item</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <img editable="true" mc:edit="feature-img1" style="display: block;" width="102" height="100" src="http://promailthemes.com/campaigner/layout2/white/blue/img/feature-img1.png" alt="feature image1" class="feature-img" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="To checkout!" class="submit" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

A few sidenotes:

- Try to avoid using tables solely for the purpose of lay-out. Use `div`'s and CSS instead, which is a much better solution.
- Different tables for each section is overkill. If you insist on using tables, use only 1.
- Separate your CSS and HTML if possible. Create a separate file for both, and link to the CSS from within the HTML page.

Comment: I am using div's and CSS, I'm just trying to a table within a div (I didn't post the whole of my code) but yes that's exactly what I want and no idea why someone downvoted it!

Comment: @user3906099 I have no idea why it has been downvoted either. I still encourage you to try and avoid tables for lay-out purposes, even the smallest ones :-) but eventually, do as you please. :-)

Comment: Was way ahead of you! was waiting for the ruddy time limit (some tihngs really need to be changed on this site!)

Comment: They will probably have these time limits for a reason ;-) Good luck with the further progress of your project!

Comment: true, true, just a tad annoying when someone has an answer but you can't seal it off for.. whatever the time limit is :) and thank you! Good luck with any ones you have ^.^